Using E2C to connect two Linux computers behind NAT
This has been asked before but I've had no success. I'm trying to connect two Linux devices via an E2C as a jump host:
[Box2 (Accessing REST API)] --> [EC2] --> [Box1 (Hosting REST API)]
What I've done:
On Box1 open up a reverse tunnel from port 6345 to port 7345 on E2C:
ssh -R 7345:localhost:6345 -i e2c_cert.pem ubuntu@xx.xx.xx.xx

On Box2 forward local 6345 port to port 7345 on E2C:
ssh -L localhost:6345:xx.xx.xx.xx:7345 -i e2c_cert.pem ubuntu@xx.xx.xx.xx

On the E2C port 7345 has been opened.
On the E2C I can see a response on Box1 when:
wget localhost:7345

But I get a connection refused on Box2 when trying:
wget localhost:6345

What am I doing wrong?

Probably your ssh -R makes the SSH server listen on the loopback interface only. What if you change your ssh -L command to ssh -L localhost:6345:localhost:7345 …?

Thanks for the comment. I've tried both the following without success:
ssh -v -R localhost:7345:localhost:6345 -i e2c_cert.pem ubuntu@xx.xx.xx.xx &
ssh -v -R localhost:6345:localhost:7345 -i e2c_cert.pem ubuntu@xx.xx.xx.xx

I did not ask you to change the ssh -R command. I asked you to change the ssh -L command and only the ssh -L command.

That works, many thanks!

My first comment is terse and therefore not a good answer by itself. I'm going to write an educative answer in few hours (unless somebody writes one first). Please don't post an answer in the question.

ssh -R 7345:localhost:6345 … makes the SSH server listen on the loopback interface only, i.e. on localhost:7345 (where localhost means the machine with the SSH server). Your other tunnel, however, uses xx.xx.xx.xx:7345 as the endpoint.
There is a way to make ssh -R use xx.xx.xx.xx:7345; it would be useful if you wanted to connect to this address from the outside. You don't need to do this and it's better (security-wise) not to do this. The other tunnel ends "inside" and it can connect to localhost:7345 if only you tell it to.
On Box2 instead of ssh -L localhost:6345:xx.xx.xx.xx:7345 … run:
ssh -L localhost:6345:localhost:7345 …

Note in this case localhost:6345 gets resolved on the client side (where ssh runs), but localhost:7345 gets resolved on the server side. The two localhost strings denote different machines.
